# reader-writer :how could this code lead to deadlock

Tags: c

```
void X() {
 lock(&m);
 while(x || y)
    wait( &farpar, &m);
 x ++;
 unlock(&m);
 // Do X stuff
 lock(&m);
 x --;
 broadcast(&farpar);
 unlock(&m);
}
double Y() {
 lock(&m);
 while(x)
     wait( &farpar, &m);
 y ++;
 unlock(&m);
 // Do Y stuff
 lock(&m);
 y --;
 broadcast(&farpar);
 unlock(&m);
}
```

In the code above, `m` is a mutex, and `farpar` is condition variable.
I am told that this could create deadlock condition, but I don't know how could this happen. BTW,`X` is writer, `Y` reader

Comment: sorry X is writer and y reader

Comment: This is not a deadlock, you are trapped into the while with a condition which is always true...

Comment: why i can't see any `farpar`s...

Answer (score 3):

You can easily run the program mentally:

- `X` locks `m`
- `X` stays in while loop, waiting for `y` to be modified by `Y`
- `Y` wants to lock `m` but mutex is already owned by `X`
- `Y` cannot update `y`
- `X` loops for ever